# Getting data from mdb database file in my Windows program

Tags: database, windows, ms-access, export

I have for some time helped a customer to export mdb table data to csv files (and then to further process these csv files). I have used Ubuntu, so mdbtools (mdb viewer) has been available to me. Now the customer wants me to automate the work I do in the form of a Windows program. I have run into two problems:

1. After some hours, I still haven't found a free tool on Windows that can export my table data in a way that I can incorporate in a program/script. Jackcess (jackcess.sourceforge.net) looks promising, but when running the downloaded jar a totally unrelated Nokia Suite program pops up...
2. I have managed to open two of the tables in a python program by using the pyodbc module, but all the other tables fail to open because of "no read permissions". Until now I thought that there were no access restrictions on the database, because mdb viewer on Ubuntu opens all tables without any fuzz. There is no other file available to be, just the mdb file. One possibility might be that this is not a permissions problem at all, but a problem with special characters in column names. All the tables that I cannot open have at least one column name with a national character, whereas the 2 two tables I can open do not. I tried to use square brackets in the SQL select called from python, like so:
   SQL = 'SELECT [colname] from SomeTable;'
   but it makes no difference. I cannot fetch data from the columns that do not contain national characters either (except from the 2 two tables that do work).

If it indeed is a permission problem, any solution must also be possible for my program to perform, there must not be any manual steps.

Edit: The developer of the program that produces the mdb files has confirmed that there is no restrictions for any tables. So, the error message "no read permissions" is misleading. I will instead focus on getting around what I presume is a problem with national characters in column names. I will start with the JSDB approach suggested below. Thanks everyone!

Edit 2: I made a discovery that I feel is important: All tables that I can open using pyodbc have Owner=Admin whereas all tables that I cannot open have no owner at all (empty string it seems, "Owner=").

Edit 3: I gave JDBC a shot. Same error again, as one could expect given the finding in Edit 2. Apparently the problem to solve is the table ownership (although MDB Viewer under Linux doesn't seem to care about that...). Since the creator of the files says he didn't introduce any permission settings, I guess the strange table ownership could be the result of using new programs (like 2010) to read data produced in a old program (like sometime in the 90s), or were introduced during some migration of the old program. Any ideas on how to solve it?

Comment: Check out this post (for JSDB): http://stackoverflow.com/a/371488/800165

Comment: Yes sorry, I meant csv. Question updated.

Comment: I haven't tried JSDB yet, but I have tried to connect to my mdb from LibreOffice Base. I got the same error message about permissions there, which suggests to me that, deep down, the same db driver as in my pyodbc approach is used, i.e. {Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}. So I guess I'm looking for alternative drivers, or alternative version of that driver. What driver(s) would be used in a JSDB approach?

Answer (score 3):

You might be able to use VBScript. VBScript is usually used in ASP files for web pages, but can be used stand alone as a Windows program as well.

VBScript is free as it's code you write in Notepad.

Others may come up with better answers for you. Good luck.

Comment: VBScript works very well with Jet/ACE, which is where the data is stored. All drivers are free to download. See www.connectionstrings.com for ADODB, though you can also use DAO in VBScript (or VB.Net, or C#).

Comment: Does my customer need to have MS Access installed to get data out of the mdb using VBScript?
Also, since {Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)} doesn't seem to work for me, are there alternative drivers that can be used with VBScript?

Comment: No, you do not need MS Access. But you do have to have the driver installed. Also, make sure you have the right driver installed. I don't know drivers real well myself, but do a search in SO for these terms to find some help: asp classic ms access ado