# HTML dynamic drop down from Excel or Access Data

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, database

I am very new to programming and taking baby steps. I am little comfortable with HTML, CSS, basic understanding of Javascript. I am trying to create a website that will help us with order processing. website will have numerous drop down menus which are interdependent. using cars as an example, if a sales person chooses Toyota, then the second drop down options should be Camry, Corolla, RAV4 etc. All these data are saved in an excel file comes from an access database. is this feasible with my current database options or do i need to invest in SQL or some other form of a database (prefer not to)? Any guidance on this would be of great help

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review the [guide for asking good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  SO is a helpful community, but you need to help us help you.  Try to accomplish this on your own and post here if you run into trouble.  Remember to be specific, and post examples of your code.  Questions that don't address specific issues with examples are almost always off-topic for this forum.

Answer (score -1):

You may want to look at this post [How to access an Access database using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370890/how-to-access-an-access-database-using-javascript) for guidance. While investing in a different database option may seem bad now, it will most likely make your life easier in the long run.

If this application actually doesn't have any web connectivity you would probably want to look into creating a non-web application with a language other than javascript.

Answer (score -1):

First, stackoverflow.com is about code, and not that much about counseling.

Second, Yes it is possible, but may not be very efficient.

Third, I can't imagine a single programming problem that needs the programmer to spend money to be solved. There are many SQL databases that are free. MariaDB (the new MySQL) and sqlite are just two examples. And these are two marvelous and outstanding SQL implementations and surpass Microsoft SQL Server and even Oracle in many aspects (Also lack some features depending on their target, but I guess you have a long way to deal with these things).

You should first estimate the volume of your data, how much will it need to be updated, and how many times the users will need to download it. Remember, the first step is the analysis of the question and not finding the answer.