# Javascript and MySQL

Tags: javascript, mysql

I want to build an entire web app using only Javascript and MYSQL . How can I go about this if it's possible.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? If it's just because you're good at Javascript, you'd be better off just *learning* another language like Ruby or Python.

Comment: Please provide more context. We'd need to know what you are trying to achieve, what you have done so far to try this and what the obstacles have been so far.

Comment: This is *very* similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298057/are-there-javascript-bindings-for-mysql. I vote for duplicate.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try something like [Jaxer](http://www.aptana.com/jaxer), which will allow you to execute JavaScript on the Web Server and query databases.

Here are some syntax examples and usages:

---

**Database, file, and socket access from JavaScript**

[alt text http://jaxer.org/images/Picture+4_0.png](http://jaxer.org/images/Picture+4_0.png)

---

**Easily create RESTful JSON data services**

[alt text http://jaxer.org/images/Picture+6.png](http://jaxer.org/images/Picture+6.png)

---

**Directly call server-side functions from the browser**

[alt text http://jaxer.org/images/Picture+2_0.png](http://jaxer.org/images/Picture+2_0.png)

---

Comment: @Dreas Grech: Jaxer was very interesting. +1

Comment: Indeed...It allows me to write a whole website with my current favorite language.

Comment: (July) Was it really worth bumping this old post with a trivial update to somebody else's old answer?

Comment: Huh, does Jaxer even exist anymore?  There doesn't seem to be anything where their site used to be.

Answer (score 2):

If you can run javascript on the server, you can build a web-application with it (without the need for any other language like PHP etc.). Search the web for 'connection string mysql' to find out how to connect to your mySQL database and use ADO/ODBC. You'll need the MySQL ODBC-connector on the MySQL server.

Here's an example database connection (where MySQL server resides on the same server as the web server):

```
function connectDB()
{
   var connectStr = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver}; " +
                    "SERVER=localhost; "                +
                    "PORT=[MySQL server port];"         +
                    "DATABASE=[your database]; "        +
                    "UID=[username];PWD=[password];"    +
                    "OPTION=3",
       conection  = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection"); 

  //ERRID=>lib::connectDB::open
   try       {connection.Open(connectStr)             }
   catch(e)  {errAlert(e,'rs::connectDB','connection failed',1) }        
   return connection;
}
```

(Where `errAlert` is a custom function to return the error)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with [Jaxer](http://www.aptana.com/jaxer). There are some screencasts that'll get you started. Also check out project [Phobos](https://phobos.dev.java.net/). Jaxer integrates nicely in Aptana studio, Phobos in Netbeans.

Answer (score 1):

You could write your application entirely in client side javascript with AJAX / REST calls to your database server - using something like [CloudKit](http://getcloudkit.com/) on your server (or CouchDB, which features a native JSON HTTP interface). On the client side, Dojo or YUI abstract out a great deal of the IO handling…

Answer (score 0):

It's quite possible to write a web application using only javascript. One the key benefits of that is that since all code runs locally, you can make an application which doesn't require online connectivity.

The main detractor though, is that you can't hook it up to a database. But there are alternative data storage hacks you can use.

One example of such a javascript application is [TiddlyWiki](http://www.tiddlywiki.com/) which is a personal wiki, contained in a single html file. The javascript application rewrites that html file, so you can carry it with you on a USB-drive or something.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at [triplify](http://triplify.org/Overview) which should expose your database as json and rdf.  I haven't actually used this but I would imagine that would let you bypass writing any server side js and talk to the database directly in a language javascript understands, using an ajax request and json.

Answer (score 0):

You can build client-side applications in javascript, with an embedded database. HTML 5 has support for databases, and a couple of browsers have already implemented this part of the spec (safari, firefox with the gears plugin).

But this is only for clientside usage. You wont be able to share the database with other users. Also you can select which database you want to use. I think gears uses sqlite.

Answer (score -3):

You will not be able to use Javascript and MYSQL without using something such as PHP on the server side to bridge the gap between the database and the Javascript on the client side.

Edit: I may be wrong, however I have no idea how you would run Javascript on the server side.

Comment: The server can be any computer running any language.