# compiler errors when starting gwt:compile with gwt-maven-plugin

Tags: eclipse, gwt, maven, m2eclipse, gwt-maven-plugin

I'm trying to migrating a gwt-project to maven for a couple of days, but keep running into problems.
I tried to follow different guides and tried different pom-configurations but didn't get it to work.
At the moment, it's like this:

- When I run gwt:compile, I get `[ERROR] Line 8: The import de.bml.web.versandanzeige.server.model.Zyklus cannot be resolved`, which is just one of many classes in my package. The error shows only up for this class. I'll post complete log below

the complete error log, with -e option:

```
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Versandanzeige_Web 1.0.2-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- gwt-maven-plugin:2.5.0:compile (default-cli) @ Versandanzeige_Web ---
[INFO] Compiling module de.bml.web.versandanzeige.Versandanzeige_Web
[INFO]    Validating units:
[INFO]       Ignored 3 units with compilation errors in first pass.
[INFO] Compile with -strict or with -logLevel set to TRACE or DEBUG to see all errors.
[INFO]    Computing all possible rebind results for 'de.bml.web.versandanzeige.client.services.KostenstelleService'
[INFO]       Rebinding de.bml.web.versandanzeige.client.services.KostenstelleService
[INFO]          Checking rule <generate-with class='com.google.gwt.user.rebind.rpc.ServiceInterfaceProxyGenerator'/>
[INFO]             [ERROR] Errors in 'file:/home/icarus/git/BML-connect/Versandanzeige_Web/src/main/java/de/bml/web/versandanzeige/client/dto/ZyklusDTO.java'
[INFO]                [ERROR] Line 8: The import de.bml.web.versandanzeige.server.model.Zyklus cannot be resolved
[INFO]                [ERROR] Line 74: Zyklus cannot be resolved
[INFO]                [ERROR] Line 77: Zyklus cannot be resolved
[INFO]                [ERROR] Line 80: Zyklus cannot be resolved
[INFO]                [ERROR] Line 83: Zyklus cannot be resolved
[INFO]                [ERROR] Line 86: Zyklus cannot be resolved
[INFO]             [ERROR] Unable to find type 'de.bml.web.versandanzeige.client.services.KostenstelleService'
[INFO]                [ERROR] Hint: Previous compiler errors may have made this type unavailable
[INFO]                [ERROR] Hint: Check the inheritance chain from your module; it may not be inheriting a required module or a module may not be adding its source path entries properly
             ... all places where Zyklus is used follow ...

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 9.406s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Nov 12 15:27:39 CET 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 13M/168M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:2.5.0:compile (default-cli) on project Versandanzeige_Web: Command [[
[ERROR] /bin/sh -c /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_07/jre/bin/java -Xmx512m -classpath /home/icarus/git/BML-connect/Versandanzeige_Web/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes:/home/icarus/git/BML-connect/Versandanzeige_Web/src/main/java:/home/icarus/git/BML-connect/Versandanzeige_Web/src/main/resources:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/sonar/sonar-plugin-api/3.2/sonar-plugin-api-3.2.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/sonar/sonar-check-api/3.2/sonar-check-api-3.2.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/sonar/sonar-colorizer/3.2/sonar-colorizer-3.2.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/sonar/sonar-channel/3.2/sonar-channel-3.2.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/sonar/sonar-duplications/3.2/sonar-duplications-3.2.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/sonar/sonar-graph/3.2/sonar-graph-3.2.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6/commons-lang-2.6.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/sonar/sonar-squid/3.2/sonar-squid-3.2.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/2.0.1/commons-io-2.0.1.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/org/picocontainer/picocontainer/2.14.1/picocontainer-2.14.1.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-annotations/3.4.0.GA/hibernate-annotations-3.4.0.GA.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-commons-annotations/3.1.0.GA/hibernate-commons-annotations-3.1.0.GA.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/guava/10.0.1/guava-10.0.1.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/1.3.9/jsr305-1.3.9.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/commons-configuration/commons-configuration/1.6/commons-configuration-1.6.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/commons-collections/commons-collections/3.2.1/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/commons-digester/commons-digester/1.8/commons-digester-1.8.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/1.7.0/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.4/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/jfree/jfreechart/1.0.9/jfreechart-1.0.9.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/jfree/jcommon/1.0.12/jcommon-1.0.12.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.6.2/slf4j-api-1.6.2.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.6.2/jcl-over-slf4j-1.6.2.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/log4j-over-slf4j/1.6.2/log4j-over-slf4j-1.6.2.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/com/thoughtworks/xstream/xstream/1.3.1/xstream-1.3.1.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/xpp3/xpp3/1.1.3.3/xpp3-1.1.3.3.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/woodstox/woodstox-core-lgpl/4.0.4/woodstox-core-lgpl-4.0.4.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/stax/stax-api/1.0.1/stax-api-1.0.1.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/woodstox/stax2-api/3.0.1/stax2-api-3.0.1.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/staxmate/staxmate/2.0.0/staxmate-2.0.0.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/xerces/xercesImpl/2.8.1/xercesImpl-2.8.1.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/xalan/xalan/2.7.1/xalan-2.7.1.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/xalan/serializer/2.7.1/serializer-2.7.1.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/sonar/sonar-gwt-api/2.11/sonar-gwt-api-2.11.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/sonar/sonar-ws-client/2.11/sonar-ws-client-2.11.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/com/googlecode/json-simple/json-simple/1.1/json-simple-1.1.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/com/google/gwt/gwt-incubator/2.0.1/gwt-incubator-2.0.1.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/com/google/gwt/gwt-user/2.5.0/gwt-user-2.5.0.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/javax/validation/validation-api/1.0.0.GA/validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/javax/validation/validation-api/1.0.0.GA/validation-api-1.0.0.GA-sources.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/org/json/json/20090211/json-20090211.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/com/google/collections/google-collections/1.0/google-collections-1.0.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager/3.5.3-Final/hibernate-entitymanager-3.5.3-Final.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/3.5.3-Final/hibernate-core-3.5.3-Final.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/antlr/antlr/2.7.6/antlr-2.7.6.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/javax/transaction/jta/1.1/jta-1.1.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/cglib/cglib/2.2/cglib-2.2.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/asm/asm/3.1/asm-3.1.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/javassist/javassist/3.9.0.GA/javassist-3.9.0.GA.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/javax/persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.0-api/1.0.0.Final/hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.0.Final.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/org/apache/geronimo/specs/geronimo-jta_1.1_spec/1.1/geronimo-jta_1.1_spec-1.1.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/log4j/log4j/1.2.14/log4j-1.2.14.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/dom4j/dom4j/1.6.1/dom4j-1.6.1.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/xml-apis/xml-apis/1.0.b2/xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/com/google/gwt/gwt-user/2.5.0/gwt-user-2.5.0.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/com/google/gwt/gwt-dev/2.5.0/gwt-dev-2.5.0.jar com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler -logLevel INFO -style PRETTY -war /home/icarus/git/BML-connect/Versandanzeige_Web/src/main/webapp -localWorkers 4 -XfragmentCount -1 -gen /home/icarus/git/BML-connect/Versandanzeige_Web/target/.generated de.bml.web.versandanzeige.Versandanzeige_Web
[ERROR] ]] failed with status 1
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:2.5.0:compile (default-cli) on project Versandanzeige_Web: Command [[
/bin/sh -c /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_07/jre/bin/java -Xmx512m -classpath /home/icarus/git/BML-connect/Versandanzeige_Web/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes:/home/icarus/git/BML-connect/Versandanzeige_Web/src/main/java:/home/icarus/git/BML-connect/Versandanzeige_Web/src/main/resources:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/sonar/sonar-plugin-api/3.2/sonar-plugin-api-3.2.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/sonar/sonar-check-api/3.2/sonar-check-api-3.2.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/sonar/sonar-colorizer/3.2/sonar-colorizer-3.2.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/sonar/sonar-channel/3.2/sonar-channel-3.2.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/sonar/sonar-duplications/3.2/sonar-duplications-3.2.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/sonar/sonar-graph/3.2/sonar-graph-3.2.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6/commons-lang-2.6.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/sonar/sonar-squid/3.2/sonar-squid-3.2.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/2.0.1/commons-io-2.0.1.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/org/picocontainer/picocontainer/2.14.1/picocontainer-2.14.1.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-annotations/3.4.0.GA/hibernate-annotations-3.4.0.GA.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-commons-annotations/3.1.0.GA/hibernate-commons-annotations-3.1.0.GA.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/guava/10.0.1/guava-10.0.1.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/1.3.9/jsr305-1.3.9.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/commons-configuration/commons-configuration/1.6/commons-configuration-1.6.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/commons-collections/commons-collections/3.2.1/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/commons-digester/commons-digester/1.8/commons-digester-1.8.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/1.7.0/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.4/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/jfree/jfreechart/1.0.9/jfreechart-1.0.9.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/jfree/jcommon/1.0.12/jcommon-1.0.12.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.6.2/slf4j-api-1.6.2.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.6.2/jcl-over-slf4j-1.6.2.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/log4j-over-slf4j/1.6.2/log4j-over-slf4j-1.6.2.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/com/thoughtworks/xstream/xstream/1.3.1/xstream-1.3.1.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/xpp3/xpp3/1.1.3.3/xpp3-1.1.3.3.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/woodstox/woodstox-core-lgpl/4.0.4/woodstox-core-lgpl-4.0.4.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/stax/stax-api/1.0.1/stax-api-1.0.1.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/woodstox/stax2-api/3.0.1/stax2-api-3.0.1.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/staxmate/staxmate/2.0.0/staxmate-2.0.0.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/xerces/xercesImpl/2.8.1/xercesImpl-2.8.1.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/xalan/xalan/2.7.1/xalan-2.7.1.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/xalan/serializer/2.7.1/serializer-2.7.1.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/sonar/sonar-gwt-api/2.11/sonar-gwt-api-2.11.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/sonar/sonar-ws-client/2.11/sonar-ws-client-2.11.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/com/googlecode/json-simple/json-simple/1.1/json-simple-1.1.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/com/google/gwt/gwt-incubator/2.0.1/gwt-incubator-2.0.1.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/com/google/gwt/gwt-user/2.5.0/gwt-user-2.5.0.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/javax/validation/validation-api/1.0.0.GA/validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/javax/validation/validation-api/1.0.0.GA/validation-api-1.0.0.GA-sources.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/org/json/json/20090211/json-20090211.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/com/google/collections/google-collections/1.0/google-collections-1.0.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager/3.5.3-Final/hibernate-entitymanager-3.5.3-Final.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/3.5.3-Final/hibernate-core-3.5.3-Final.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/antlr/antlr/2.7.6/antlr-2.7.6.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/javax/transaction/jta/1.1/jta-1.1.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/cglib/cglib/2.2/cglib-2.2.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/asm/asm/3.1/asm-3.1.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/javassist/javassist/3.9.0.GA/javassist-3.9.0.GA.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/javax/persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.0-api/1.0.0.Final/hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.0.Final.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/org/apache/geronimo/specs/geronimo-jta_1.1_spec/1.1/geronimo-jta_1.1_spec-1.1.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/log4j/log4j/1.2.14/log4j-1.2.14.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/dom4j/dom4j/1.6.1/dom4j-1.6.1.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/xml-apis/xml-apis/1.0.b2/xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/com/google/gwt/gwt-user/2.5.0/gwt-user-2.5.0.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/com/google/gwt/gwt-dev/2.5.0/gwt-dev-2.5.0.jar com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler -logLevel INFO -style PRETTY -war /home/icarus/git/BML-connect/Versandanzeige_Web/src/main/webapp -localWorkers 4 -XfragmentCount -1 -gen /home/icarus/git/BML-connect/Versandanzeige_Web/target/.generated de.bml.web.versandanzeige.Versandanzeige_Web
]] failed with status 1
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:322)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:158)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.ForkedProcessExecutionException: Command [[
/bin/sh -c /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_07/jre/bin/java -Xmx512m -classpath /home/icarus/git/BML-connect/Versandanzeige_Web/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes:/home/icarus/git/BML-connect/Versandanzeige_Web/src/main/java:/home/icarus/git/BML-connect/Versandanzeige_Web/src/main/resources:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/sonar/sonar-plugin-api/3.2/sonar-plugin-api-3.2.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/sonar/sonar-check-api/3.2/sonar-check-api-3.2.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/sonar/sonar-colorizer/3.2/sonar-colorizer-3.2.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/sonar/sonar-channel/3.2/sonar-channel-3.2.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/sonar/sonar-duplications/3.2/sonar-duplications-3.2.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/sonar/sonar-graph/3.2/sonar-graph-3.2.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6/commons-lang-2.6.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/sonar/sonar-squid/3.2/sonar-squid-3.2.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/2.0.1/commons-io-2.0.1.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/org/picocontainer/picocontainer/2.14.1/picocontainer-2.14.1.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-annotations/3.4.0.GA/hibernate-annotations-3.4.0.GA.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-commons-annotations/3.1.0.GA/hibernate-commons-annotations-3.1.0.GA.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/guava/10.0.1/guava-10.0.1.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/1.3.9/jsr305-1.3.9.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/commons-configuration/commons-configuration/1.6/commons-configuration-1.6.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/commons-collections/commons-collections/3.2.1/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/commons-digester/commons-digester/1.8/commons-digester-1.8.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/1.7.0/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.4/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/jfree/jfreechart/1.0.9/jfreechart-1.0.9.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/jfree/jcommon/1.0.12/jcommon-1.0.12.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.6.2/slf4j-api-1.6.2.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.6.2/jcl-over-slf4j-1.6.2.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/log4j-over-slf4j/1.6.2/log4j-over-slf4j-1.6.2.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/com/thoughtworks/xstream/xstream/1.3.1/xstream-1.3.1.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/xpp3/xpp3/1.1.3.3/xpp3-1.1.3.3.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/woodstox/woodstox-core-lgpl/4.0.4/woodstox-core-lgpl-4.0.4.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/stax/stax-api/1.0.1/stax-api-1.0.1.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/woodstox/stax2-api/3.0.1/stax2-api-3.0.1.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/staxmate/staxmate/2.0.0/staxmate-2.0.0.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/xerces/xercesImpl/2.8.1/xercesImpl-2.8.1.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/xalan/xalan/2.7.1/xalan-2.7.1.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/xalan/serializer/2.7.1/serializer-2.7.1.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/sonar/sonar-gwt-api/2.11/sonar-gwt-api-2.11.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/sonar/sonar-ws-client/2.11/sonar-ws-client-2.11.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/com/googlecode/json-simple/json-simple/1.1/json-simple-1.1.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/com/google/gwt/gwt-incubator/2.0.1/gwt-incubator-2.0.1.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/com/google/gwt/gwt-user/2.5.0/gwt-user-2.5.0.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/javax/validation/validation-api/1.0.0.GA/validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/javax/validation/validation-api/1.0.0.GA/validation-api-1.0.0.GA-sources.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/org/json/json/20090211/json-20090211.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/com/google/collections/google-collections/1.0/google-collections-1.0.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager/3.5.3-Final/hibernate-entitymanager-3.5.3-Final.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/3.5.3-Final/hibernate-core-3.5.3-Final.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/antlr/antlr/2.7.6/antlr-2.7.6.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/javax/transaction/jta/1.1/jta-1.1.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/cglib/cglib/2.2/cglib-2.2.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/asm/asm/3.1/asm-3.1.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/javassist/javassist/3.9.0.GA/javassist-3.9.0.GA.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/javax/persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.0-api/1.0.0.Final/hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.0.Final.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/org/apache/geronimo/specs/geronimo-jta_1.1_spec/1.1/geronimo-jta_1.1_spec-1.1.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/log4j/log4j/1.2.14/log4j-1.2.14.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/dom4j/dom4j/1.6.1/dom4j-1.6.1.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/xml-apis/xml-apis/1.0.b2/xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/com/google/gwt/gwt-user/2.5.0/gwt-user-2.5.0.jar:/home/icarus/.m2/repository/com/google/gwt/gwt-dev/2.5.0/gwt-dev-2.5.0.jar com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler -logLevel INFO -style PRETTY -war /home/icarus/git/BML-connect/Versandanzeige_Web/src/main/webapp -localWorkers 4 -XfragmentCount -1 -gen /home/icarus/git/BML-connect/Versandanzeige_Web/target/.generated de.bml.web.versandanzeige.Versandanzeige_Web
]] failed with status 1
    at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.AbstractGwtShellMojo$JavaCommand.execute(AbstractGwtShellMojo.java:485)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.CompileMojo.compile(CompileMojo.java:365)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.CompileMojo.doExecute(CompileMojo.java:280)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.AbstractGwtShellMojo.execute(AbstractGwtShellMojo.java:172)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    ... 19 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <!-- for gwt-incubator -->
        <id>sonar</id>
        <name>Sonar</name>
        <url>http://repository.sonarsource.org/content/repositories/sonar</url>
        <releases>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.sonar</groupId>
        <artifactId>sonar-plugin-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.2</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>ejb3-persistence</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.sonar</groupId>
        <artifactId>sonar-gwt-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.11</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- unit tests -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.sonar</groupId>
        <artifactId>sonar-testing-harness</artifactId>
        <version>2.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.7</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.3-Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
        <artifactId>geronimo-jta_1.1_spec</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.14</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<groupId>de.bml-con</groupId>
<artifactId>Versandanzeige_Web</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
<build>
    <outputDirectory>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/java</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.java</include>
                <include>**/*.gwt.xml</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <webappDirectory>src/main/webapp</webappDirectory>
                <webXml>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
                <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <webAppConfig>
                    <contextPath>/${project.name}</contextPath>
                </webAppConfig>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <logLevel>INFO</logLevel>
                <style>PRETTY</style>
                <gwtVersion>2.1.0</gwtVersion>
                <runTarget>de.bml.web.versandanzeige.Versandanzeige_Web/Versandanzeige_Web.html
                </runTarget>
                <modules>
                    <module>de.bml.web.versandanzeige.Versandanzeige_Web</module>
                </modules>
                <copyWebapp>true</copyWebapp>
                <webappDirectory>src/main/webapp</webappDirectory>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>gwtcompile</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <!-- manage dependencies -->
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <includeTypes>jar</includeTypes>
                <stripVersion>true</stripVersion>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-invoker-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-deps</id>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <projectsDirectory>.</projectsDirectory>
                        <pomIncludes>
                            <pomInclude>pom.xml</pomInclude>
                        </pomIncludes>
                        <streamLogs>true</streamLogs>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>dependency:copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

project structure:

sources:

[image]

webapp:

[image]

This project is already under version control, so I'd try to avoid starting anew.

How can I fix this problem, make it compile into a war and start in debug mode?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11516675/java-util-linkedlist-nodee-can-not-be-assigned-to-gwt-serializable/11534536#11534536. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6575501/gwt-database-access-without-rpc/6577352#6577352.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

GWT 101: client code cannot refer to server code.

More specifically:

> [INFO]             [ERROR] Errors in 'file:/home/icarus/git/BML-connect/Versandanzeige_Web/src/main/java/de/bml/web/versandanzeige/client/dto/ZyklusDTO.java'
>   [INFO]                [ERROR] Line 8: The import de.bml.web.versandanzeige.server.model.Zyklus cannot be resolved

and the `server` subpackage probably has no corresponding `<source path="server" />` in your `de/bml/web/versandanzeige/Versandanzeige_Web.gwt.xml` (totally understandable though). See https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects#DevGuideDirectoriesPackageConventions and https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsClient

Comment: You are completly correct.
I could swear though, that this is quite an old piece of code and the GWT-Plugin-Compiler never complained about it...

Answer (score 1):

Is your gwt module description missing ( xxx.gwt.xml) ?