# jQuery: <IMG/> element on-the-fly

Tags: jquery, dom, on-the-fly

Here is the problematic part of my code, run inside .each(function(){  });

```
$('img','<div>'+ed.selection.getContent({format: 'html'})+'</div>').each(function(){  
  $img=$('<img/>').attr('src',$(this).attr('src'));
  alert($('<p>'+$img+'</p>').html());
  if ($(this).attr('height').length>0){
    $img.attr('height',$(this).attr('height'));
  }
  if ($(this).attr('width').length>0){
    $img.attr('width',$(this).attr('width'));
  }
  alert($img.html());
});
```

First, i'm working with the selected tinyMCE content in html format which is fust fine as jQuery recognizes it properly. $img.html() returns empty value, not undefined but just blank. Tested both FF 3.6 and IE8. Can someone explain, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `html()` function only returns the contents of the element. Since `<IMG>` is technically empty, you get an empty string.

If you had this:

```
<span>The text</span>
```

and you asked for `$span.html()`, you'd get just `The text`, without the enclosing tags.

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in accessing the `<img>`'s content then have a look at [Question number 298049](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298049/can-i-access-the-datafile-of-an-img-tag-from-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

[`.html()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/html) gives you the innerHTML of an element i.e. what's inside it.  An `<img>` doesn't have anything inside it - it's an empty element.

You have the right idea by wrapping it and taking the innerHTML of that.

Answer (score 0):

An image element doesn't have any inner HTML, therefore the method can't return any.